# Editing Typo3 CMS front-end page

Tags: typo3

I get a project that used TYPO3 CMS, the task is quite simple, adding cookie usage notice on the header part of the website.

I never working on TYPO3 before, but already reading the documentation. Somehow I can't figure out which file to edit. even the documentation tutorial and file structure is different than the project I handle.

I don't have any project documentation for the project either, and I don't want to ask you to do my task, but I'm blank at the moment and don't know where to find the respective file needed.

Any suggestion or clue how to handle the issue?

my index.php on root folder look like this:

```
if (defined('E_DEPRECATED')) {
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);
} else {
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
}


// ******************
// Constants defined
// ******************

define('PATH_thisScript', str_replace('//', '/', str_replace('\\', '/',
    (PHP_SAPI == 'fpm-fcgi' || PHP_SAPI == 'cgi' || PHP_SAPI == 'isapi' || PHP_SAPI == 'cgi-fcgi') &&
    ($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED'] ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED'] : $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']) ?
    ($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED'] ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED'] : $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']) :
    ($_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ? $_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME'] : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))));

define('PATH_site', dirname(PATH_thisScript).'/');

if (@is_dir(PATH_site.'typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/')) {
    define('PATH_tslib', PATH_site.'typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/');
} elseif (@is_dir(PATH_site.'tslib/')) {
    define('PATH_tslib', PATH_site.'tslib/');
} else {

// define path to tslib/ here:
$configured_tslib_path = '';

// example:
// $configured_tslib_path = '/var/www/mysite/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/';

define('PATH_tslib', $configured_tslib_path);
}

if (PATH_tslib=='') {
    die('Cannot find tslib/. Please set path by defining $configured_tslib_path in ' . htmlspecialchars(basename(PATH_thisScript)) . '.');
}

// ******************
// include TSFE
// ******************

require (PATH_tslib.'index_ts.php');
```

**edit:** adding screenshot of the interface suggested by @Riccardo (typo3 ver 4.4.4)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of TYPO3 are you running? As Bernd wrote, it is difficult to help you without further information.... I'll try to explain the first passages where you could gather some infos.

1) Access TYPO3 backend with a user with administrative privileges

2) Try to identify the main TypoScript template with this procedure:

[image: Select TypoScript Template]

- click on template (1)
- click on the "zero" page with the TYPO3 symbol (2)
- you should see on the right a list of the TypoScript templates (3),
  click on the one that is marked as "is Root"

2) After that, click on the first dropdown on the right area (with the "info/modify" item and select "TypoScript Object Browser" (a.k.a. TSOB)

[image: Select TSOB]

3) After you have done that, you should see a "tree" that represents the TypoScript configuration;

- be sure to have "setup" selected (1)
- search for the object that builds your page, which should most likely be `page = PAGE` (2)

[image: TypoScript TSOB tree]

[answer edited]

I'm afraid I'll have to ask for a survey supplement

Can you identify in which part of the various objects the header of your site is rendered? My suspects would be focused on the `[home2]` or the `[outer_frameset]` object; 
Hoping that they will contain the usual array with something like:

```
home2.10 = something
```

I think that the quickiest (and dirtiest) way to append something *before* the whole page would be something like

```
home2.1 = TEXT
home2.1.value = <div>whatever your message would be </div>
```

I don't know if you need something more complex than that...

Said that, I admit I never worked with frame inside TYPO3 and I think that the last time I did something with frames was...uh... maybe 9 years ago.

Comment: hi Riccardo thank you for the detail info! I found out that the typo3 version is TYPO3 4.4.4. I add the screenshot on question, can you elaborate which one to edit? thanks!

Comment: Aside of the usage of such an old and far outdated version of TYPO3 (even the OS must be outdated for the old PHP version) the page uses a frame layout which fails all SEO recommendations. I think you have far bigger problems with that site than a missing GDPR compliance. the workload to update that installation to a supported one would be very much and I would do a relaunch from scratch doing it in a modern way using modern responsive frameworks. (PS: I think I identified the website and it looks awfully broken.)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't change that index.php!!**
As it is part of the core which gets overwritten on an update of TYPO3.

As there are very much options for configurating a page there can be no recipe matching all.

My best tip: get a TYPO3 profi to have a look into your installation so he can find which files are responsible for the page rendering and could include the cookie notice.
There also are some extensions which could render such a notice in your pages in a very easy way. But that all depends how your installation is configured. Nothing to say without further knowledge.

Comment: Is there no common place to see where the main template is? like joomla or wordpress we can locate the theme/template

Comment: you need to understand typoscript(TS), the configuration of TYPO3.You can see the resulting TS for each page in the TSOB, but that could vary on conditions. Then you need to find the place where this part of TS has been defined (/last modified). The output can be done in TS directly, or done with marker-templates, newer installations probably use fluid-templates. those can be splitted in sub-templates. nearly any part of the HTML can be generated by plugins (PHP), which might be configured by TS and might use their own marker- or fluid-templates. TYPO3 is very flexible, so you can do anything.